# Don't want to copy pictures to another worksheet, which code should I use?

Tags: vba, excel

I need to copy and paste from one worksheet to another worksheet by using VBA. But there are some pictures in Column B, which I don't want to copy and paste to another worksheet column A. Part of my code is listed below. I need to add some code to exclude pictures, but don't know which one I should use. Please advise. Many thanks

```
sh.Range("b" & i).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Order List").Range("A" & j)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to copy any objects in that range, you could use:

```
Application.CopyObjectsWithCells = False
' your copy code here
Application.CopyObjectsWithCells = True
```